# No logro instanciar la clase en java

Tags: java, método

Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
public class Clientes extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtusuario;
    private JPasswordField clave;

    public Clientes() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel Usuario = new JLabel("Usuario");
        Usuario.setBounds(10, 11, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(Usuario);

        txtusuario = new JTextField();
        txtusuario.setBounds(66, 8, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtusuario);
        txtusuario.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 46, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

        clave = new JPasswordField();
        clave.setBounds(66, 43, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(clave);

        JButton btnEntrar = new JButton("ENTRAR");
        btnEntrar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        btnEntrar.setBounds(63, 188, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnEntrar);

        JButton btnSalir = new JButton("SALIR");
        btnSalir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.exit(0);

            }
        });
        btnSalir.setBounds(229, 188, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnSalir);
    } // fin del constructor


    public String getPass() {
        return clave.getPassword().toString();
    }
}//Fin de la clase
```

Mi pregunta es: Cómo puedo accesar el método getPass() del codigo anterior. en la siguiente clase:

```
public class DatosUsuario {

    private String usuario1="";
    private String pass1="";

    Clientes cliente = new Clientes();


    cliente.??
}
```

No me aparecen los métodos. Gracias

Comment: El cliente.?? no debería estar dentro de otro método o el constructor ?.. ahi donde está no tiene sentido

Comment: Técnicamente es posible. Si embargo no tiene sentido debido a que Clientes no ha sido inicializado con valores.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu método `getPass()` no esta declarado como estático tienes que instanciar la clase y de esta forma puedes llamar el método:

```
Clientes cliente = new Clientes();
String password = cliente.getPass();
```

---

```
public class DatosUsuario {

    private String usuario1="";
    private String pass1="";

    Clientes cliente = new Clientes();
    String password = cliente.getPass();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eso debe ser por el IDE o editor de textos que estás usando.

```
Clientes cliente = new Clientes();
String pass = (String) cliente.getPass();
System.out.println("passw:"+pass);
```

Yo uso Visual Studio Code y se visualizan los métodos sin problema alguno. Intenta probar algún otro editor.